# Where does e come from in this problem about dice?

Tags: probability, asymptotics

A few days ago someone asked a [question about dice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600294/a-three-dice-roll-question) in an interview. Naturally, one can consider the following more general problem. Suppose there are $n$ dice, with numbers from $1$ to $n$, on them. Person A throws $(n-1)$ dice in total, and person B throws a single die. Player B wins if his number is larger than the maximum of all the numbers of person A. What is the probability that B wins in this game?

The simplest approach is to consider a sequence $(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1},b)$. We wish to count all such sequences so that $b$ is larger than $a_i$. We can choose $n$ choices for $b$ and then $(n-1)$ choices for the $a_i$. Therefore, the probability that person B beats person A is equal to, $\frac{(n-1)^{n-1}n}{n^n} = \left( 1 - \tfrac{1}{n} \right)^{n-1}\approx \frac{1}{e}$.

Mysteriously the answer here involves $e$. Is there some deeper explanation for where this quantity comes from? This answer reminds me of the classical "*hat problem*" to which the answer is also (approximately) $\frac{1}{e}$. In both problems it is unclear to me what exactly is causing these constants to appear.

To clarify, when we say "deeper reason", we mean in reference to some deep result in probability theory. For instance, there are some problems which are approximated with an answer involving $\pi$, however, those problems are clear since they are variants of the Central Limit Theorem in some form or another, so it is not a surprise where this constant came from.

What exactly is the limiting distribution here that makes $e$ appear? I remember I once read about "order statistics", but I never learned anything about them, perhaps, by taking the maximum it is the asymptotic of the top order statistic? (It would be helpful is someone can also explain where $e$ likewise comes from in the hat problem as well.)

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - \tfrac{1}{n})^n = \tfrac{1}{e}$ Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: That is not the question, furthermore, you meant to write $e$ not $1/e$, in either case, the question is asking for a limiting probability distribution, not calculus.

Comment: I fixed the typo. This is the limit of a function, in this case, the distribution is a function that has this limit. Probability distributions do not have their own calculus.

Comment: I am not sure what the purpose of your comment is. The question already wrote that limit in there, why repeat it again?

Comment: If you know that's the limit, what is your question?

Comment: For example, if you have $2n$ coins, then the probability that exactly $n$ heads will come up is approximately $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$. The heuristic explanation here ("deeper" than just using Stirling's formula), is the CLT, we divide by $\sqrt{n}$ as expected, and in the CLT we have a presence of a $\pi$ factor. So the answer "makes sense" in reference to some deeper result in probability. Perhaps, $\max(U_1,U_2,...,U_n)$ undergoes some other distribution as $n\to \infty$ which leads to $e$ (where $U_i$ are discrete uniforms)?

Comment: $e$ is intimately related to circular functions (they are equivalent), which is why virtually any question related to Euclidean geometry in two or more dimensions potentially involves this number (as well as $\pi$).  It shows up in many 1D problems, too, because the real line is part of the complex plane.  Asymptotic questions are typically analytical, meaning they involve infinitesimal properties of the real line.  Thus, the interesting observation is not why $e$ shows up, but why in any such question it does *not* appear!

Comment: The description of the game doesn't match your calculations.  If B needs to exceed the *maximum* of A's numbers, then in order to select a sequence in which B wins, we have $n$ choices for the number $b$, but only $b-1$ choices for each of the remaining $a_i$, not $n-1$.  These calculations would describe a game where B wins if his number is *different* from all of A's numbers (not necessarily greater).  Is that perhaps what you had in mind?

Comment: If $n = 2$, then the probability of B beating A has nothing to do with $e$. I agree with @NateEldredge: the formula you used doesn't match the description of the game.

Comment: I feel like the answer here is kind of a tautology.  It seems elementary (for the appropriate version of the game) that the probability is given by $\lim (1 - \frac{1}{n})^{n-1}$.  The fact that this equals $1/e$ is a pretty direct consequence of the fact that $\lim (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n = e$, which is turn is effectively the *definition* of $e$.  So the question is kind of like asking why does one plus one equal two.  It's because that's what "two" *means*.

Comment: There are other possible definitions of $e$, such as $e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$, or that $e$ is the unique nonzero value of $a$ for which $f(x) = a^x$ is its own derivative.  It's a standard exercise to show all three define the same number.  So if this isn't satisfying, I would turn the question around and ask you: to you, what defines the number $e$?  Then we could talk about why it makes sense for the number with that definition to appear here.

Comment: For a probabilist, maybe the most "fundamental" property of $e$ is that $1/e$ gives the probability for a Poisson process of rate 1 to have no arrivals in 1 unit of time. That could even be considered as the definition of the number $e$. And as $n$ goes to infinity, the number of A's rolls that match B's roll does indeed converge to a Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 10):

The reason $e =\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n}=\frac1{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n}}$ appears is precisely because you are taking a particular limit, though I am not sure you took exactly the correct one.

The answer should head towards $0$ as $n$ increases, since player B has one die and player A has an increasing number of dice.  Ignoring the possibilities of ties for the largest values, you might think the probability of player B having the largest of $n$ values might be $\frac1n$.  But the possibility of ties changes this.

You have used $n$ to mean two different things: the numbers of/on the dice and the number thrown by $B$.  If instead you had used $b$ as the number thrown by player B then the answer to "the probability that Player B's number is *strictly larger* than the maximum of all the numbers of person A" is $$\sum\limits_{b=1}^n \frac{(b-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$$ which for large $n$ is approximately $\frac{1}{n(e-1)}$, about $\frac{0.58}n$.

Meanwhile "the probability that Player B's number is *at least as large* as the maximum of all the numbers of person A" would be $\sum\limits_{b=1}^n \frac{b^{n-1}}{n^n}$ which for large $n$ is approximately $\frac{e}{n(e-1)}$ about $\frac{1.58}n$.

From the difference, you can tell that the probability of player B's number being exactly equal to the largest of player A's numbers is $\sum\limits_{b=1}^n \frac{b^{n-1}-(b-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}=\frac1n$. An alternative approach would be to say that the largest of player A's numbers is some value from $1$ to $n$  and player B has a probability of $\frac1n$ of getting that exact value.